# Open fillable .pdf file, edit it and save with JS

Tags: javascript, pdf

Any simple way to open .pdf file that contains editable parts (like checkboxes) with JavaScript (probably with pdf.js), allow to edit it, sign it (on mobile/tablet or with a mouse) in a browser and save as new .pdf with server-side (RoR in my case)?